# Plotting the Scherk surface with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

How would one go about plotting the Scherk surface with TikZ?
The Sherk surface is defined as the graph of

log(cos(x)/cos(y)), where -pi/2 < x,y < pi/2

I tried this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm, compat=1.16}

\pgfplotscreatecolormap{bw}{color=(lightgray) color=(white) color=(lightgray)}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}
            [
            view={60}{30},
            hide axis,
            colormap name =bw,
            ]
            \addplot3[surf,shader = faceted interp,
            domain=-pi/2+0.0001:pi/2-0.0001,
            domain y = -pi/2+0.0001:pi/2-0.0001,
            samples=20,
            colormap name =bw,
            samples y=20,
            ]
            ({x},
            {y},
            {log10(cos(deg(x))/cos(deg(y)))});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

but only got 'ugly' results...
Is there a way to plot the Sherk surface in this way (with this colormap etc.)?
I already plotted the helicoid in a similar way and want the pictures to "look the same" (same colormap and stuff)...

The desired aesthetic would be:

[image: helicoid]

What I got is:

[image: scherk]

But I'd rather get something like

[image: scherk]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What, please, is a Sherk surface? Can you please explain better?

Comment: I added a definition of the Scherk surface...

Comment: Could you post code (or at least an image) for your helicoid so we can see your desired results?

Comment: The samples do not really change the looks of it. I tried to increase them (in both x and y) but the quality did not get better

Comment: If I use `-pi/2+.1:pi/2-.1` for the domains, it looks much better. I guess your domain is still too close to pi/2 for TeX/pgfplots to produce a better curve and the rest gets crushed somehow.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: No the plot is not crushed, and there is nothing wrong. The plot simply goes to infinity at the limits, so the plot is perceived different dependent on the z scale.

Comment: I can not find `pgfplotscreatecolormap` in the TikZ or in the PGFPlots manual - is it a low level variant or maybe something from older versions of PGFPlots? Edit: ok obviously it is not from TikZ as it contains `pgfplots...`

Comment: @hpekristiansen That's exactly what I meant. The middle is so flat because the border is relatively high.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Ok - I read it wrong. Your "somehow" made be believe that you thought that there is an error in PGPPlots or in the formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{colormap={CM}{color=(lightgray) color=(white) color=(lightgray)}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
view={60}{30},
hide axis,
zmin=-0.4, zmax=0.4,
trig format plots=rad,
clip=false,
]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=faceted interp,
domain=-pi/2+0.1:pi/2-0.1,
samples=20,
] ( x, y , {log10(cos(x)/cos(y))} );
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Scherk surface gray shaded]

**Edit:** The same plot with these limits: `domain=-pi/2+0.0001:pi/2-0.0001,`

[image: Scherk surface gray shaded with higher wings]

The important thing is not the limits, but the z-scale. As you do not show any z-axis, the choice `zmin=-0.4, zmax=0.4` is only based on how "round" you would like the plot to appear - your original plot is not wrong.